# Rails 3 Migration with longtext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-3

I am needing to change a column type from text to longtext in my Rails script, but can't find anything on how to do this.

Has anyone ran across this?

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: (for rails 2 at least, you can just specify type :longtext FWIW)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The `text` type handles `tinytext`, `text`, `mediumtext`, and `longtext` for MySQL, if that's what you're using. Just specify the upper bound using `:limit => ...`

Example:

```
change_column :articles, :body, :text, :limit => 4294967295
```

The default value of `limit` is 65535, as expected.

```
1 to 255 bytes: TINYTEXT
256 to 65535 bytes: TEXT
65536 to 16777215 bytes: MEDIUMTEXT
16777216 to 4294967295 bytes: LONGTEXT
```

The MySQL documentation can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html#id733892).

Comment: What happens if you don't know the limit?

Comment: Updated with a comprehensive list.

Comment: It should be "4294967295" and not "4294967296" (i.e., `4.gigabytes - 1`) or else `Mysql2::Error: Display width out of range for column ....` is raised.

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect that. Thanks a bunch Vikrant.

Comment: On mysql 5.1.52 I used a limit of `16.megabytes - 1`, but I still got a longtext, not a mediumtext. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Same for me, even though specifying t.text "bla", :limit => 16777215 , the resulting column type is "longtext".

Comment: All: This was a bug in Rails. It has been patched as of a few weeks ago in the 4.0 branch.

Comment: @ChuckCallebs: Could we get a link to the PR that fixed this issue and what version of Rails it's supposed to be shipped in?

Comment: How do I get the max limit? can I do `:limit => :max`? I'm trying to get an equivalent of SQL server's `NVARCHAR(MAX)` but I am migrating to postgres

Comment: As noted by @DavidM. above, the different MySQL TEXT data types have different sized overheads. http://rricketts.com/mysql-difference-tinytext-text-mediumtext-longtext/ has a handy table for reference.