# Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'help_ru', Rails 4 and Mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have model that have help_ru column that is set as text datatype.

**Problem**: I tried to update help_ru column from my ActiveAdmin panel, but received error message `Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'help_ru'`  .

I tried to add text that has 170 000 characters with spaces. It takes aprox. 40kb when saved in text document.

I am using **TinyMCE** so the text includes styling information. Please,see small example of it:

```
<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">Sludinājuma izvieto&scaron;ana</p>\r\n<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">Bezmaksas sludinājumu apraksts:</p>\r\n<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">1. Lietotājam ir tiesības ievietot vienu bezmaksas sludinājumu Individualki.eu sadaļā.</p>\r\n<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">2. Lietotājs var ievietot vienu bezmaksas sludinājumu vienu reizi 14 (četrpadsmit) dienās. Pēc 14 (četrpadsmit) dienām sludinājums tiks automātiski dzēsts.</p>\r\n<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">Maksas sludinājumi :</p>\r\n<p style=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in; line-height: 115%;\">3. Maksas sludinājumus var: pievienot,
```

I double checked help_ru column's datatype and **it is text** not string (like in similair questions that I found in StackOverflow.).

I am using Mysql as database.

Why this problem persists if I don't have special restrictions and text datatype is very large?

Thanks

Comment: I found great help in this answer - >http://stackoverflow.com/a/4443512/1460362